# laravel show database values in my blade front end foreign keys values

Tags: php, laravel, database

So I'm new to laravel and I'm trying to figure out a way to connect my database with my front end!

First this is the villa model for the table villas:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Villa extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable=[
        "id", "title", "description", "price", "state", "status", "city_id", "seller_id", "payment_id", "created_at", "updated_at"
    ];
    public function City()
    {
        return $this -> hasOne(City::class,'id','city_id');
    }
    public function Seller()
    {
        return $this -> hasOne(Seller::class,'id','seller_id');
    }
    public function Payment()
    {
        return $this -> hasOne(Payment::class,'id','payment_id');
    }
}
```

this is the website controller : and here I'm trying to call the table

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Models\Villa;
use App\Models\City;
use App\Models\VillaImg;

class WebsiteController extends Controller
{
public function index(){
        $villas = DB::select('select * from villas');
        return view('website',['villas'=>$villas]);


}
```

this is the website blade which I use this way to call the value but I don't know how to call a foreign key value , for example :
I have the foreign key city_id and I want the show the city name on my front end but don't know how

```
 @foreach ($villas as $user)
    <a href="single-villa.html" id="villaname">{{old('name',$user->title )}}</a>
  @endforeach
@foreach ($villas as $user)
  <a href="#" id="villaLocation">{{old('city',$user->I don't know what to write here)}}</a>
 @endforeach
```

Note: this is a code in a div that represents a villa block.
Also, I'm not sure if this is really the correct way to do so and I want to know if there's another efficient way to do that!

here's the route:

```
Route::get('/',[WebsiteController::class,'index'])->name('home.index');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use eloquent orm instead of db facade...

```php
$villas = Villa::with(['City', 'Seller', 'Payment'])->get();
```

and then if u need any relation value:

```php
@foreach ($villas as $villa)
    {{ $villa->City->property }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: I see, I have another question since I have more than one villa each with its id, how can I call it by its id?

Comment: this query will return all records from villas table with those 3 relations. If u have another model that has relation to this one (Villa) then u need to call that one and pass with Villa parameter.

If u here want to list specific villa by id u can do something like:
$villas = Villa::where('id', $id)->with(['City', 'Seller', 'Payment'])->first();

$id is id that ur comparing to, u need to pass it through either get or post method to the controller.
Why we use first() method here? Because u want to load 1 data row. Always care for performance issues, n+1 queries is most common mistake.

Comment: thank u! I was wondering if you can help me with my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73487103/laravel-redirect-to-page-based-on-id-from-database-is-selected) @cile1993